# Visualforce Help - Field Arrangement

Tags: visualforce, community

I would like to place my picklist field "Overview_Status__c" on the top right next to my "Save" button, but I'm unsuccessful.  Click on the link for a visual. Thanks for helping.

My VF code:

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/11ac28f1-d11b-4c32-b6e3-ae826a1c9527/7d63688433dd5cf4e419e03507de1e44

```
<apex:form id="formOverview">
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="out1aa">
    <div align="right" draggable="false" >
        <apex:commandButton style="float:centre; width:75px" value="Save"/
    </div>

    <apex:pageBlockSection >       
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ReportsWithIndex}" var="repWrapped">
            <div align="center">
            <apex:column style="width:100%">
              <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
              <apex:inputField style="display:block;width:100px;" value="{!repWrapped.rep.Overview_Status__c}" required="false" />
            </apex:column>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>  

 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: But your Overview_Status__c field is iterating in pageBlockTable,  means it will show more times.... ? so do you want to put this pageblocktable by the left side of Save button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unfortunately your code doesnt work in my environment without the controller.So I'm just going to stab this in the dark and say that your picklist needs to be within the button's div?

P.S Managed to get this working with a simple picklist

```
 <div align="right" draggable="false" >
<apex:selectList id="selected_list" required="false" size="1" onchange="changeColor(this,'tabOne');">
                    <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemvalue="inprogress" itemLabel="In Progress"/>
                    <apex:selectOption itemvalue="completed" itemLabel="Completed"/>
                </apex:selectList>   
                 <apex:commandButton style="float:centre; width:75px" value="Save"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: any chance you know how to retain the status?  When I closed my VF page and come back in, and the status are reset.  Thanks

Comment: You'll need to store the value of the picklist upon save, I would say. But cant provide any code examples, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would say @kazoolsky 's answer will probably already work for you. But for a little further statement:

`<apex:pageBlockTable>`is not customizable. It's just using Salesforce standard style. So if you want to customize it, use `<apex:dataTable>` instead.

I find `<apex:pageBlockSection>` not customizable as well. So probably just get rid of it.

You can put float for both divs to achieve the result you want.

Comment: If I got an upvote from you sir, it should count for a hundred regular upvotes, right?=) Love reading the information you guys provide us with, here!

Comment: @kazoolsky I am flattered for that. Already upvoted for you